# I try to build with platform iOS and I have this error ionic Cordova

Tags: ios, macos, cordova, ionic-framework, apple-m1

I try to build with platform iOS and I have this error : [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova platform add ios@latest --save exited with exit code 1.
    
    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more
    information.
```

Comment: have you tried `--verbose` flag to your command

Answer (score 0):

try build ios with this command :

**ionic cordova build ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"**